# Eliminating a column from a copied feature class via a fieldmap object in ArcGIS Python

Tags: python, arcgis-9.3, field-mapping

The use case is exporting a feature class via a Python script (arcgisscripting v9.3x.  Only a few of the columns are needed in the result feature class.

I commonly use the fieldmappings/fieldmap objects to rename columns. The docs state that you can also use them to delete a field as the feature class is being exported.  Can anyone provide an example of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last sample in the [Mapping input fields to output fields](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z00000014000000.htm) help topic has a python example of removing a field from a field map. Here's the relevant code:

```
fieldmappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()
<snip>
fieldmappings.removeFieldMap(fieldmappings.findFieldMapIndex("TRACTCODE"))
```

That is for 10 but it looks like there were similar methods at 9.3:  [FieldMappings properties](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?id=1011&pid=980&topicname=FieldMappings_properties)

Comment: I hadn't seen that method, but it is in the 9.3 object model.